# Unchecked conversion using Class.cast()

Tags: java, generics, casting, warnings, unchecked

My goal is to fix the following **warning**:

`[unchecked] unchecked conversion
            retValue = WidgetSelectionModel.class.cast(new EllipseSelectionModelImpl(canBeSelected));
  required: WidgetSelectionModel<T>
  found:    WidgetSelectionModel
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Shape declared in method <T>getSelectionModel(Class<T>,boolean)`

Here the code of my class

```
public <T extends Shape> WidgetSelectionModel<T> getSelectionModel(final Class<T> shapeClass, final boolean canBeSelected) {
   return WidgetSelectionModel.class.cast(new EllipseSelectionModelImpl(canBeSelected));
}
```

Comment: try this   return (WidgetSelectionModel<T>)new EllipseSelectionModelImpl<T>(canBeSelected));

Comment: This given an other warning :  [unchecked] unchecked cast